# How to do PHP loops correctly

Tags: php

> Write a class called math.  It is to have one property called num. It also has one method (function) called factorial.  This method is to start at 1 and multiply all of the integers to num.  If num is 5 then you would multiply 1*2*3*4*5.  Of course you are to do this in a loop.

Which loop should I use? For or do while? Also, do I need an inner loop? 
I started with

```
For (i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
{

}
```

however, i'm stuck on what to do next...any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using any loop. `for` loop can be converted to `while` and `do .. while` and opposite is true too.

```
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
```

is same as

```
i=0; while(i<5){i++;}
```

To to find the factorial you should multiply all the values from 1 to the number you want factorial of. So if `$num = 5`. Only one single loop is needed. You'd want to run this loop.

```
for($i=1;$i<$num;$i++){
    $num*=$i;
}
```

**I am not giving a full solution here because the question seems homework**. If I give you full solution it will be spoon-feeding.

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = 1;
$target = 5;
for ($i = 1;$ i <= $target; $i++)
{
    $result *= $i;
}
echo $result;
```

or

```
$result = 1;
$target = 5;
while($target > 0) {
    $result *= $target;
    $target--; // You could do this all in one line, but for learners, this is clearer.
}

echo $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

Each iteration you will want to multiply the total of the factorial by the value of `$i`

```
class Math {

    public static function Factorial($factorial) {
        $output = 1;

        for($i = 2; $i <= $factorial; $i++)
            $output *= $i;

        return $output; 
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've gotten to where I prefer the `while(i--)` loop:

```
<?php

class Math {

    public $num = 0;

    public function factorial() {
        $result = 1;
        $num = $this->num;

        while ($num) {
            $result *= $num--;
        }

        return $result;
    }

}

$factor = new Math();

$factor->num = 5;

echo $factor->factorial();

?>
```

http://codepad.org/hUOgAoz2